# loop through the pixels of the image sql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following problem and I think I have the solution but I am not quite sure.

> Assume an image with size 1000x1000 stored as the single object
>   contained in collection Image. That image has components red and nir
>   (for “near infrared”). The Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
>   (NDVI) gives an estimate for vegetation in a given pixel, based on
>   these two bands. Write a query which returns the NDVI of the whole
>   image.

This is the sql statement that I thought:

```
Select img.red AS red, img.nir AS nir, ((img.nir-img.red)/(img.red+img.nir)) AS NDVI FROM Image AS img
```

Since it is supposed in the problem that the image(and the image has 1000X1000 pixels) has the components red and nir, I think that the select statement will loop through all the pixels. Or is that not correct?

Thank you

Comment: The `SELECT` statement will loop through all _records_.  How are you storing the 1000x1000 array in your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Assume a 1,000 x 1,000 image stored as the single object contained in collection Image. - That's all I have.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-geometrycollection.html